# How to create another bootstrap collapse navbar button?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a fixed navbar top similar to Udemy using bootstrap 3. This contains a left aligned collapsible drop down. But copying `navbar-header` twice didn't work.  CSS is not my strong point. Any direction is appreciated.

[image]

Collapsed one on left and one on the right.

[image]

## Update

This is what I have so far. I would like the button group items to adopt the default behaviour of bootstrap (with icon-bar) on the left most corner of navbar when resized for smaller displays.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <header class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>          
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <div class="btn-group header-dropdown nav navbar-nav">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Select City</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <span class="caret"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">Chennai</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Bangalore</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Mumbai</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Others</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
</nav>
```

Comment: why are you trying to copy navbar-header twice ?

Comment: Like I said, I am clueless :-) I thought because the `icon-bar` class is under `navbar-header` so I had to replicate.

Comment: [boot strap docs for navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

Comment: What you have tried share some code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a `dropdown` to create the "Discover" menu, and some custom CSS to center the brand. The links on the right would toggle/collapse on small screens using the `navbar-collapse`..

**Working demo:** http://bootply.com/133215

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided any code, it's difficult to determine what's going wrong with your project. Your dropdown should look something like this, probably inserted just before the other navbar elements:

```
<div class="btn-group pull-left">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="sr-only">Button text</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>

  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns